# Efficiency of querying an SDL_Surface for pixel colors

Tags: c++, performance, sdl, sdl-2

I'm writing a game that has a simple 2D map and needs to determine which "region" on the map the user clicked. Each region has a unique RGB color associated with it. So, given the `(x,y)` coordinates of a click, I do this:

```
Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *) image_surface_->pixels;
Uint32 pixel = pixels[(y * image_surface_->w) + x];
Uint8 r, g, b;

SDL_GetRGB(pixel, image_surface_->format, &r, &g, &b);

SDL_Color rgb = {r, g, b, 255};
```

where `image_surface_` is the `SDL_Surface` which contains the map that was loaded into the game's `SDL_Window`.

After the bit of code above, I run through the list of regions and check which of them has a matching color value.

My question is, what is the efficiency of querying an `SDL_Surface`'s pixels? Is it just `O(1)` as appears to be the case because all you're doing is indexing a pointer? Or is there more going on?

(For the actual game I'm writing, poor efficiency doesn't matter much, but I plan on developing a mini-engine for the writing of 2D (and potentially, 3D games) that use a map, which could theoretically be very large with many regions)

Comment: It is indeed O(1) but I wouldn't be using functions lie SDL_GetRGB if you can avoid it. Per pixel inner loop stuff is best done without calling a function or needing an if statement (ie branching). You can make the "pixel" pointer uint8_t* so that you can address the individual rgb components like pixel[RED_OFFSET], pixel[BLUE_OFFSET] for example.

Comment: @fret What is the reason I should avoid calling a function?

Comment: @ubadub function call is not free, and said function have a branch inside it. If target CPU don't have branch prediction - that will not be great to call it too many times in a loop (e.g. iterating through entire image). Not terrible, but you can do better without extra function call or braches.

Comment: @keltar what are the values of `RED_OFFSET`, `BLUE_OFFSET`, etc.?

Comment: @keltar never mind, I got it. Leaving it here for anyone else who needs it: `(pixel & image_surface_->format->Rmask) >> image_surface_->format->Rshift;`

Comment: This is not the right way to do it for more reasons than efficiency. Its actually less code and simpler to just translate the point; you already know where you are drawing everything.

Comment: Also, this code is wrong. You should always use `surface->pitch` instead of width for calculating which row you are on. Even then this of course will be broken if you ever need to use it for a non 32 bit surface. Another reason to just do it the right way so you aren't needlessly shackled to specific formats.

Comment: @BradAllred I don't follow. The code above is exactly the same code used in the source code for the SDL library. Why would it be wrong?

Comment: @ubadub its wrong because its quite common for an image to have a greater pitch than its width; this may not be true for surfaces crated with `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`, but not all surfaces are created that way. I highly doubt the source code for SDL uses `surface->w` in such a calculation; if it does than that is wrong too. You will end up on the wrong pixel (or possibly empty padding) using this method in such a case.

Comment: Sure thing, even with CreateRGBSurface it will align pitch to 4 bytes, so it may be wrong for RGB or any other non-32bit formats. I kind of assumed 32bit because `Uint32` indexing; if that's not the case, this code will be wrong for more reason then just wrong pitch.